# While loop not working properly?

Tags: java, if-statement, applet, while-loop

This is more or less my first java project. I can't get my `while` loop to work properly. It seems to loop as many times as the integer I input for my first option. But I want it to for my second one. My computer teacher isn't very helpful at all.

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Summative extends JApplet
{
    int n; //first choice variable
    int t; //time variable
    int integer; //integer input
    int x=0; //count variable
    int y=50; //test

    public void init() //Initialize method
    {
        setSize(1000, 800); //Set size

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setBackground(Color.GREEN); //Set background
    }    


    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint(g); //Start paint method

        g.setFont(new Font("Veranda", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.drawString("Hello", 250, 25); //top display message

        String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like a custom loop count or an infinite? 1.  Custom   2. Infinite"); //test choice
        n = Integer.parseInt(number);
        while (n<0 || n>2);

        if (n==1);
        { 
        }
        do
        {
            String number2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many times would you like to loop?");
            integer = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }while (integer<0 || integer>99999);


        while (x < integer)
        {   
            g.drawString("hi", 200, y); 

            x+=1;
            y = y+40; //test

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant this

```
integer = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

to be

```
integer = Integer.parseInt(number2);
```

Comment: thanks for the tip on the semicolons, helped clean up the code. And @seth thanks for the fix there, that fixed it. Screwed up the variable :P

Answer (score 4):

It's worth pointing out that you have a couple of stray semicolons in your code:

```
while (n<0 || n>2);
                  ^ HERE
```

and

```
if (n==1);
         ^ HERE
```

Also, you never actually look at `number2` (the second `parseInt()` call looks incorrect).